# Why do Ionic Lifecycle hooks (ionViewWillEnter, ionViewWillLeave) not fire when used as HTML Selector?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive, ionic4

I am working on an Angular Project, with Ionic 4.

When Child Page is called from Parent Page's HTML using HTML Selector, child page's Ionic Lifecycle Hooks do not fire.
Why is it so? How do I use these hooks?

Child Page:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.page.scss']
})

export class ChildPage {

     ionViewWillEnter() {
         console.log(`ionView-Will-Enter`);
         // Code goes here...
     }

     ionViewWillLeave() {
         console.log(`ionView-Will-Leave`);
         // Code goes here...
     }
}
```

Parent HTML:

```
<ng-container>
    <app-child></app-child>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ionic Page lifecycles executes on routing components, so you have to use routes in order to this work. [Chek it here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle#ionic-page-events).

Of course you can use the Angular lifecycle hooks in this case.

Note that you can load components/pages to your template via selector and via routes.

EDIT:

Here you have a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-oknxaz?file=src/app/example/example.component.ts) to make some test. Note the logs provided by execution of Angular example component lifecycle hook OnInit and the Ionic pages lifecycles.

I've added logs for ngOnInit, ngAfterViewInit, and ngOnDestroy Angular lifecycles hooks to the stackblitz. You can see that works fine and maybe this ones fits your needs.

Comment: How do I add a child's page to parent's template via routes?

Comment: Remember that he outlet acts as a placeholder to load the page that match the current route. Normally you have an `<ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>` on the top of your app so if you define a new route pointing a page, when you hit that route the page loads in that outlet, but if you want to load the page inside a specific parent page, you have to include an outlet in this parent page. I'm going to add an example to the answer.

Comment: I want my code to route to the child page, when the condition is true for the ng-container, in the Parent Page. I don't want an click event, or anything manually, for the routing to happen. Can that be done?

Comment: You could `import { Router } from '@angular/router';` in your parent component, inject it `constructor(private router: Router) { ... }` and then use `this.router.navigateByUrl('urlString');` or `this.router.navigate(['routeSegment']);`  to navigate to a specific route programatically. You also need to include the route for that component in the array of routes in the module or routing module that you choose to load the component. `{path: 'child', component: ChildComponent}`. For more info you could check the oficial doc at https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: But how do I do it from the parent's html ?

Comment: In the html you can show/hide elements (via selector) with Angular *ngIf directives. The use case of this directive is show/hide parts of your page, not to simulate navigation to another page.

Comment: I understand it is to show/hide.
Based on my condition, I wanted to show the child component (example added below), but the ionic lifecycle hooks did not fire, so I wanted to know if it is possible (from the Parent's html page itself) to call the Child component and also have the hooks.

<ng-container *ngIf="true">
     <app-child></app-child> 
</ng-container>

Comment: Is not posible that the Ionic life cycles got executed with that structure. The render of the component happens via selector and the Ionic life cycles of a component occurs when that component renders hitting to its corresponding route. Is not the same thing Angular lifecycle hooks and Ionic life cycles. In your case you could still using Angular lifecycle hooks for ChildComponent, but not Ionic life cycles.